# Hyper-V virtual machine management service stuck at ‘Stopping’

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v

After installing the KB5009624 monthly rollup from Microsoft, we are experiencing a problem wherein suddenly both the Hyper V instance and the Host Machine become unreachable using the virtual switch.

When we try to shut down the virtual machine using Hyper-V manager, we get an ‘Access Denied’ error and also we are unable to shut down the virtual machine using the command prompt.
We have also installed the Update (KB5010419) that was supposed to fix the errors mentioned in the previous KB5009624 update. But our problem has repeated even after installing the update (KB5010419).

We have gone through the below article which suggests a similar problem, but according to Microsoft this error exists with “Broadcom NetXtreme 1-gigabit network adapters”, but we are using an Intel X540 network adapter.

*https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/vm-lose-network-connectivity-broadcom*

Environment: The host machine is running Windows Server 2012 R2 and the virtual machine is Windows 10.

What we have tried so far:

1. Disabling and enabling the adapters inside the VM.
2. Disabled & enabled host network adapter (Both physical and virtual switch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our issue was solved after uninstalling the KB5010419 and KB5009624 Windows updates.